# How to send a POST request using volley with Collection of string

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to send POST request with collection of string in the body parameters. Below is sample of my request format-

```
{
  "Emails": [
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2"
  ]
}
```

and here is what I am trying-

```
private void sendEmailRequest(final String email, String playId) {
    String url = "https://someurl";
    Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
    postParam.put("Emails", "["+ email +"]");

    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new JSONObject(postParam),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());              
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + myToken);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest, tagStringReq);
}
```

but it always goes to **onErrorResponse** method with error logs-

```
E/Volley: [613] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://someurl
```

Please give me suggestions to overcome from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Body request of your JSON structure:

```
{
  "Emails": [
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2"
  ]
}
```

Is like this:

```
 try {
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put("sample string 1");
    array.put("sample string 2");
    body.put("Emails", array.toString());

    new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, body, listener, listener);
    ....
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     // ignores exception
 }
```

Note: When you use `JsonObjectRequest` you do not need to add a content type. I am refering to this line:

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```